# how to detect integration of my website on other websites?

Tags: javascript, c#, web, iframe, integration

is there a simple way to find out if my website is being integrated e.g. via iFrame/ JS on another page?
I am planning on writing a C# tool to detect these external uses of my page for statistics.

I am currently trying to read the request header from the client so that I can access the "referrer". This should indicate if a user is coming from an external site or just clicked a link on mine.

Is it possible to convert the request.header into a JSON so that I can access the referrer like this: .referrer?

```cs
string headers = String.Empty;
            List<string> headerlist = new List<string>();
            foreach (var key in Request.Headers.Keys)
            {
                headers += key + "=" + Request.Headers[key];
                headerlist.Add(headers);
            }
```

Comment: My bad. It's off-topic. Questions asking us to **recommend** or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and **what has been done so far** to solve it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for explaining. How is it now?

Comment: Now I voted to reopen :)